# How to set DataGrid Header's font size programatically from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, styling

I'm wondering how could I set my `DataGrid` `Header` Font size programatically, in case I would like to keep my font size in the database, because sometimes user might move aplication to a smaller monitor(1024x768) let's say and that simply he might edit his font size and everything is gonna be fine.

This is `Style` I am using right now to style my header:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
</Style>
```

So how could I set this properties from code behind if I would like to

Could I do simply smth like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
</Style>
```

I changed `<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>`

to

```
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize}"/>

Value="{Binding FontSize}" //is new
```

so how can I add value to this `FontSize` to be something from my code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example add a double property to your window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public double MyFontSize { get; set; } = 30;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

---

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding MyFontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    </Style
</Window.Resources>
```

Note that if you want to be able to change the value of the source property dynamically at runtime, the window class (or wherever you choose to implement the property) should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event and raise change notifications.

Comment: Is there way to do this also when I am setting ItemsSource to my DataGrid, maybe I can provide one more attribute in my class? for example price, article name, phone and font size and I could do this : Value="{Binding MyFontSize}" ?

Comment: An item in the ItemsSource represents a row in the DataGrid but the column header is common for all rows so it doesn't make much sense to specify the font size of the header in the data object.

Comment: how could I set FontSize for my DataGridColumnHeader from my public static Global class where I'm keeping value of my fontsize?

Comment: Please don't ask questions in the comment field.

Comment: sorry mate I thought it too much related to each other because you explain it when there is property defined on Window which contains DataGrid: Value="{Binding MyFontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" but I wanted to know how to do it if property is defined somewhere else in Global static class.. but whatever I can post another question about that because I am struggling with it for 5h allready :/